# Swift retrieve data from Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I've have tried different attempts of retrieving data from firebase (Database), but sadly with no luck :I... So I was wondering If this is the correct way of doing it?

```
let dBRef = Database.database().reference()
         dBRef.child("Users").child("Advertisements").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

    let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

        let imageAd = snapshotValue?["imageAd"] as? String
        let priceAd = snapshotValue?["priceAd"] as? String
```

Im not sure if I actually receive the data, and Im not sure of how to test this as well... I have tried debugging but with no luck...
So my question is, is my code wrongly done? and if not how do I check If I actually receive the data??

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are observing the `childAdded` event.

So your closure will only be executed when a **new value** I inserted into `Users/Advertisements`.

Try this code instead

```
Database
    .database()
    .reference()
    .child("Users")
    .child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)
    .child("Advertisements")
    .queryOrderedByKey()
    .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

        guard let dict = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] else {
            print("Error")
            return
        }
        let imageAd = dict["imageAd"] as? String
        let priceAd = dict["priceAd"] as? String
    })
```

The closure will be executed only once and "almost" immediately.

Comment: So I don't need to do it this way? dBRef.child("Users/(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)/advert‌​isements")

So the error isn't by missing the uid part??

Comment: @StrawHat Yes, you also need to add the userID. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Cheers, but how am I able to test and see if I ever retrieve the current available data from the database??? I have no way of really testing this ? Im not so familiar wit this you see..

Answer (score 1):

to test if your data was pulled in accurately, you can add, below your code: `print(imageAd)`. assuming this code is in `viewDidLoad` then it will show up in the console when the view controller comes up.

also, I believe `.queryOrderedByKey(...)` is now `.queryOrdered(byKey:...)`

keep in mind that `.observe()` essentially opens a connection to your firebase. if you want a live, realtime connection to stay open and listen for updates to data, this makes sense. if you only need the data once, when you load something, consider using `.observeSingleEventOf()` instead. if you are going to use `.observe()` , you should also use `.removeAllObservers()` to close the connection when you need it to be closed.

it seems like you are just trying to add this info which you've previously set up in your DB. I would do it like this - (keep in mind you were missing the uid step in your json. I have assumed it is the current user in the code below, but if it's a static user, you'd need to define it as a string):

```
let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid 
dBRef.child(Users).child(uid).child(Advertisements).observeSingleEvent(of: 
   .value, with: { (snapshot) in

  let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
  let imageAd = value?["imageAd"] as? String ?? ""
  let priceAd = value?["priceAd"] as? String ?? ""

  print("imageAd: \(imageAd!)")
  print("priceAd: \priceAd!)")`
  })
```

Comment: I see, but my aim is to list a set of data into a tableView, thats why I dont use obserSingeEvent... Or do you suggest this just to see if there is actually being fetched?

Comment: this would initially show you data is being fetched through the print statement. can you clarify what you aim to present in the table view?

Comment: You can use a single event and populate the table view with that. The difference is for example if you had other users  who were inputting data while the current user was looking and you wanted to update the data in real time. Observing is akin to standing outside and watching for things to happen. Single event is going outside and taking a picture of everything that is there in that moment. What you do with the data afterward is independent of that.

Comment: Okay!, Well for now the database Is strutted that I save the image I take and push up to the DB (from another ViewController) as a URL (string)... So before I try to convert stuff and get the real image into a UIImageView... I just want to see the URL inside of the UITableView... Just so that I make sure of I retrieve data and I can set it into a labelTextField... Which I am struggling with at the moment

Comment: Are you getting something to print in the console when you run this code? This code should answer the question you asked above. You may want to ask another question if your question is now a different one.

Answer (score 0):

I can see one problem is that your path is wrong. Try something like:

```
let dBRef = Database.database().reference()    
dBRef.child("Users/\(FirAuth.auth.currentUser.uid)/advertisements")

dbRef.queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate of why the way I sat it up is wrong? thanks

FirAuth.auth.currentUser.uid is wrong? it dosen't exist it says..

Comment: Sure, what I meant to say was that in your db reference you're doing "users/advertisement/" but your ref should be "users/userid/advertisements" you're skipping the userid

Comment: Arh so it should be like;

        dBRef.child("Users/\(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)/advertisements")
.. I just changed it, but seems like nothing happens, is there a way for me to test if I actually receive data? debug a variable or trying something else??

Comment: yeah but I'm going to have to see more code or feel free to send me your project. I don't know where you're trying to retrieve your data or display it (trying to figure out what you're trying to do)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem as yours but by looking at the firebase Doc you can see how to retrieve data easily.

```
lazy var databaseRef = Database.database().reference().child(yourpath).("Advertisements")

ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            let postDict = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] ?? [:]

            if let email = postDict["Email"] {
                print(email)

            }



        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
```